# hector indoor SLAM demo: rviz crashes

Tags: rviz, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz crashes when I try to run the [hector quadrotor indoor SLAM demo](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20indoor%20SLAM%20demo) (plus another bunch of warnings show up). Gazebo however starts. I tried it on groovy. One of the relevant problems is that the configuration file for rviz is in the old format (.vcg), whereas it expects a YAML (.rviz) file.

How do I solve this? Shall I convert the file? How do I do it?

```
$ roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo indoor_slam_gazebo.launch 
[...]
process[rviz-10]: started with pid [1591]
ERROR: the config file '/home/kr1zz/workspace/rosbuild_ws/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/hector_quadrotor_apps/hector_quadrotor_demo/rviz_cfg/indoor_slam.vcg' is a .vcg file, which is the old rviz config format.
       New config files have a .rviz extension and use YAML formatting.  The format changed
       between Fuerte and Groovy.  There is not (yet) an automated conversion program.
[rviz-10] process has died [pid 1591, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz -d /home/kr1zz/workspace/rosbuild_ws/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/hector_quadrotor_apps/hector_quadrotor_demo/rviz_cfg/indoor_slam.vcg __name:=rviz __log:=/home/kr1zz/.ros/log/6ae55fe6-4625-11e3-8234-5404a69cc0c7/rviz-10.log].
log file: /home/kr1zz/.ros/log/6ae55fe6-4625-11e3-8234-5404a69cc0c7/rviz-10*.log
loading model xml from ros parameter
[...]
```

(I trimmed the rest of the output but I can post if required)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97941/hector-indoor-slam-demo:-rviz-crashes/) by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe the rviz config file format is not right

> hector_quadrotor_demo/rviz_cfg/indoor_slam.vcg' is a .vcg file, which is the old rviz config format

i am using indigo distro for me its .rviz format maybe you should try converting the file from .vcg format to .rviz format

---

Originally posted by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) with karma: 90 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1